# Never ask again for turning on GPS

Tags: android, service, dialog, gps, location

I have a function in Kotlin that enables GPS in app. Is that possible to change dialog box by adding a checkbox with a parameter like "Never ask again" in order to avoid turning on GPS all the times when user open app?

Or maybe there is a kind of another solution like making a custom dialog box?

Here is a code:

```
private fun buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
    val mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
        .setInterval(2000)
        .setFastestInterval(1000)
    val settingsBuilder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
        .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest)
        .setAlwaysShow(true)
    settingsBuilder.setAlwaysShow(true)
    val result = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this).checkLocationSettings(settingsBuilder.build())
    result.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        try {
            task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
        } catch (ex: ApiException) {
            when (ex.statusCode) {
                LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED -> try {
                    val resolvableApiException = ex as ResolvableApiException
                    resolvableApiException.startResolutionForResult(this, 100)
                } catch (e: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"PendingIntent unable to execute request.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE -> {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "Something is wrong in your GPS",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings):

If the device is running Android 6.0 or higher, and your app's target SDK is 23 or higher, the app has to list the permissions in the manifest and request those permissions at run time. For more information, see Requesting Permissions at Run Time.

If your app targets Android 10 (API level 29) or higher and needs to access the device location while your app is in the background, you must also declare the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission. To learn more, see the section on how to request access to background location.